# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el valor de borderRadius.Circular de la pantalla de iPhone en Flutter?

Tags: flutter, ios

Quiero obtener el valor de borderRadius.Circular de la pantalla del dispositivo. Con el fin de redondear el BottomNavigationBar en base a ese valor obtenido. Y dejarlo algo así como tiene el Dock de iOS cuando tienen pantallas redondeadas como el iPhone X, iPhone Xs, iPhone 11, iPhone 12, iPhone 13. Y el resto de dispositivos como el iPhone SE, iPhone 7, iPhone 8, tienen el Dock cuadrado sin bordes redondos.

[image: 2 iPhones con Dock diferentes, el uno cuadrado y el otro redondeado]:

Se que en Android no es posible obtener ese valor, pero al menos quisiera obtenerlo en iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En lugar de detectar el redondeo de los bordes (no he encontrado info sobre eso).

Podrías detectar el espacio inferior del SafeArea, eso lo puedes hacer con:

```dart
MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding.bottom
```

Si es mayor que cero podrías considerar que el dispositivo tiene bordes redondeados y mostrar tu nav bar con bordes circulares.

Comment: Perfecto, funciona. Muchas gracias.